# Coveo DNE feature -new facet styling

Tags: coveo, contact-facets

I'm going to implement a new `Coveo` feature [Dynamic navigation](https://docs.coveo.com/en/1671/coveo-machine-learning/coveo-machine-learning-features#dynamic-navigation-experience-dne-feature)

When I define CoveoDynamicFacet instead of CoveoFacet, I automatically get a new facet style with that.

**Is there a way to keep the old styling?**

**If yes:**

```
What is the scope of work to maintain existing (old) facet styling?
How much additional work is needed to maintain our existing(old) facet styling?
```

**new styling:**

[image]

**and old one:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach for this would be to modify the Coveo stylesheet (or reference your own) to add new styling rules (copying the styles that you like) in order to overwrite the styling rules for Dynamic Facets.

As far as maintenance, you'll need to make sure your new styling rules are applied during any future upgrade of the Coveo framework. Since I would say most Coveo implementations require modifying the stylesheet, this maintenance wouldn't be outside of the norm of what you would be normally doing during a Coveo upgrade.